# Should the same object always return the same serialized string?

Tags: php, serialization

When php returns a serialized string, does it only rely on the input value or do outside sources (the environment) play any part at all?

The reason why I am asking this is, I am seeing some arrays that I believe to be identical get serialized slightly different per session.

I wrote this which demonstrates that they are always the same within the same session:

```
<?php
    $arr = array("something here", "foo" => "something else", "bar" => array( "nested" => "temp", 5232), 3434);

    $s = serialize($arr);

    for( $i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++ )
    {
        $s2 = serialize($arr);
        if( $s2 != $s )
        {
            echo "They are not always the same";
            break;
        }
        if($i == 100)
        {
            echo "They are always the same";
        }
    }
?>
```

So either there is something causing them to be created differently on different connections, *or* my arrays that appear to be identical are somehow not.

Comment: Can you post the different serialized array strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialized strings are human readable. They can be broken down as follows:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:14:"something here";}
```

The first letter is the datatype, array, the number is the length/size of the object. So next up you have an integer of 0 and then a string 14 characters in length. So now you can read the format can you see any differences?

When I run your [code on codepad](http://codepad.org/Ah1HyLtB) it works as expected. So perhaps there is more at play here like in your actual code you are trying to serialize an object.

Comment: Your explanation of how serialization works led me strait to the problem, the same value was actually a string in one "s:1" and a number/digit in another "d:1"

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following example:

```
$array1 = array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'quux');
$array2 = array('baz' => 'quux', 'foo' => 'bar');

var_dump($array1 == $array2);
var_dump(serialize($array1) == serialize($array2));
```

So arrays which are equal (non-strict comparison) might not necessarily give the same serialization. But if you were to sort the arrays, they would give the same serialization; environment/platform etc. do not affect the outcome.

In general, classes can implement their own serialization, either using the old [__sleep() and __wakeup()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.sleep) or by [implementing Serializable](http://php.net/serializable), so there's no guarantee that the same object serializes to the same string each time (e.g. it might include time or counter etc.).

Comment: +1 Good answer, in my case it was outputting the same when debugging but the data types were actually different like: `array("foo" => 7)` and `array("foo" => "7")`

Comment: That's an even simpler use case, didn't think of that!